# Why the OuputIterator concept doesn't have a value_type associated?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, c++-concepts, iterator-traits

I am programming a library where I need to make an iterator interface and I want to make it as general as possible.

```
template<class OutputIterator>
void receive(OutputIterator oit){
    auto val = get_function< std::iterator_traits<OutputIterator>::value_type > (); // legacy function
    oit = val;
}
```

To my surprise for most output iterators `value_type` is `void`. (`void` renders the code invalid because a `void` variable cannot be declared).

Here two examples:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator

However in both cases there is an obvious value type associated, I could hack into each and "see" that there is a value type. For example `back_insert_iterator::container_type::value_type` (but not accessible from `iterator_traits`).

**Why is the standard trying to hide the `value_type` of the output iterators?**

Maybe the correct terms is not `value_type` but there is obviously some type associated. Is this an overlook? Am I using the output iterator incorrectly?

Comment: The theory is that an output iterator may accept more than one type: "**[iterator.requirements.general]/1** ... All output iterators support the expression `*i = o` where `o` is a value of some type that is in the set of types that are *writable* to the particular iterator type of `i`..."

Comment: Aren't `OutputIterator`s kind of like sinks for data?  You push data into them but you can't get data out of them.

Comment: What's the value type of [`ostream_joiner`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ostream_joiner)?

Comment: @T.C. , `void` :) .    Some output iterators don't have a type associated but for those that do is very difficult to get.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, ok, some output iterators don't need to have a value type associated, but it seems that the standard when to far in forbidding to report a value type for the output iterators that clearly do have one associated.